# Why is the responsive function not working?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

In the given [link](https://codepen.io/zameelm10/pen/eYgbNBZ), why is the reponsive effect of the navbar disappearing not working ?

```
 <nav>
<li>Hello</li>
</nav>


<style>@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
   .nav {
      display: none;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: You're targeting an element with the class nav with the dot, aka `.nav` means class of nav. You want `nav` with no dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you use class selector `.nav` instead of tag selector `nav`.
Also You are lacking bracket to end thy media-query.

Change it and it should work

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply styling to the nav element without the dot(.)

```
   nav {display: none;}
```

[This is how you select elements in css.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element.asp)

Also it looks like you are missing a closing curly bracket before style.